# Правильно ли происходит проверка округления времени?

Tags: php

В переменной `$time` может быть следующее время (`0:12`,`01:22` и тд). При разбиении строки я получаю `$time[0]==0` или `01`. Правильно ли я делаю проверку на наличие одной цифры в этой переменной?

```
$time=explode(":",$value); 

print_r($time);
if($time[0]<=10 and strlen($time[0])==1){
    $minutes="0".$time[0];
}else{
    $minutes=$time[0];
}
```

Comment: А что вам мешает самостоятельно проверить правильность работы этого кусочка кода с различными входными данными?

Comment: Действительно, напишите юнит-тесты и проверяйте. Поддерживаю вопрос @Kromster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dateTime = strtotime($time);
echo date('H:i',$dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Объект DateTime. http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time);
$minutes = $dateTime->format('i');
```

Форматы времени. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: подставил значения  не работает пишет Call to a member function format() on boolean in

Comment: @G_test_00 Да, я подумал что исходные данные это минуты:секунды. Минуты и секунды должны содержать 2 числа. А если это часы:минуты, тогда будет работать. Для часов достаточно 1го символа. Я исправил ответ.